# Run Selenuim Test Case/Suite without using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testing, selenium, selenium-grid

I've been doing some searches for running exported selenium tests/cases, and all I found was running it in Eclipse and using the TestNG plugins. Is there any way I could run them without using eclipse? Like running it via command line. I'm using a Windows VM by the way for my Selenium Grid server and node. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: There are ways. It would depend on how you wrote your tests and whether you are using any test framework like junit or testng?

Comment: Thanks, I just record and export them in the Selenium IDE in TestNG format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testng tests can be invoked via command line.  Documentation [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng)

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse **you can invoke your test using command line no matter you are using which framework either Junit or TestNG**.

**Even you can write your tests in main method of a java class without using any framework** and run that java program from commandline as usually we do.

For running a **Junit test case through command line** refer this link : [Junit from command line](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_4)

For running a **TestNG test case through command line** refer this link :[Running TestNG from command line](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng)